# Argument Exception thrown by PtrToStructure

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling, hid

Can someone please explain the following Argument Exception : **The structure must not be a value class** to me please.
It's being cause by the following line of code in my program:

```
Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, dbh);
```

given that `dbh` is of type:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Device_Broadcast_Header
{
    public int dbch_size;
    public int dbch_devicetype;
    public int dbch_reserved;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot call this particular [`Marshal.PtrToStructure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30ex8z62.aspx) overload with a value type (i.e. a `struct`).

If you call [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx) you can receive an instance of your type back.

Comment: For example: `dbh = (Device_Broadcast_Header)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(Device_Broadcast_Header));`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for not giving a code example, but here is a [link](http://207.46.19.190/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.interop&tid=9b5d0652-cc9c-4ab1-87c2-baa5405d988c&cat=&lang=&cr=&sloc=&p=1) that might help you.

Here is the key text from the above link:

> The problem does nothing with the
>   RegisterTraceGuids API.
>
> According to the doc of
>   Marshal.PtrToStructure(IntPtr, Object)
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30ex8z62.aspx
>   , it throws the ArgumentException that
>   you saw when structure layout is not 
>   sequential or explicit or structure is
>   a boxed value type.
>
> In this case, the structure is
>   declared as sequential, however, the 
>   elements in the array
>   (traceGuidReg[i]) are boxed on the
>   managed heap  because of the array
>   object, thus you got the error "the
>   structure must not  be a value class."
>
> You would need to use the overload
>   Marshal.PtrToStructure Method (IntPtr,
>   Type) 
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx
>   and assign the result of
>   PtrToStructure to the array elements.

Comment: Thanks Jas I kind of hit the solution befor e you replied and that site also, but can you explain what thet guy meant by the elements being boxed on the Managed Heap? I think I have a fair idea what this could mean but I'd like clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class Device_Broadcast_Header_Wrapper{
    public Device_Broadcast_Header Header
}

Device_Broadcast_Header_Wrapper wapper = new Device_Broadcast_Header_Wrapper();
Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, wapper);
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written